# Use actionbutton to move to the next row of dataframe in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the `shiny` app below in which when the user clicks on a row of the datatable a subset happens in another dataframe `df` and a text is displayed.

I want when I press the `Next` `actionbutton()` the text to display the data of the next row of the subseted dataframe. In this case it should display `"flower b has score 5"`.

My original data will have many rows so when pressing `Next` everytime I need to adapt the text based on the correspondent row.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 textOutput("celltext"),
                 actionButton("next","Next")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tableId = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris[,c(1,5)],  selection = list(target = 'row',mode="single")
    )
    species<-c("setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica")
    flower<-c("a","b","c","d")
    score<-c(7,5,6,9)
    df<-data.frame(species,flower,score)
    
    observeEvent(input$tableId_rows_selected, {
    output$celltext <- renderText({
      cell <- input$tableId_rows_selected
      dat<-df[df$species %in% iris[cell,5],]
      df <-dat[order(dat$score,decreasing = T),]
      df
      paste("flower",df[1,2],"has score",df[1,3])
    })
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining `reactiveValues` object will help.  Perhaps you are looking for this

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 textOutput("celltext"),
                 actionButton("next","Next")),

  server <- function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(text=NULL)
    dt <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    output$tableId = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris[,c(1,5)],  selection = list(target = 'row',mode="single")
    )
    species<-c("setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica","setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica")
    flower<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
    score<-c(7,5,6,9,1,2,3,4)
    df<-data.frame(species,flower,score)

    observeEvent(input$tableId_rows_selected, {
      row <- input$tableId_rows_selected
      dat<-df[df$species %in% iris[row,5],]
      dt$data <-dat[order(dat$score,decreasing = T),]
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[1,2],"has score",dt$data[1,3])
      rnum(1)
      output$celltext <- renderText({
        rv$text
      })

    })

    observeEvent(input[['next']], {
      rnum(rnum()+1)
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: what if there are more than 2 rows?my original data has many rows

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Do you wish to go to next row every time you click NEXT button?

Comment: yes but my df it only has 2 rows now would it work if my dataframe had 3 rows or more? If you replace for example all virginica with setosa my subseted dataset will have 4 rows.

Comment: I added some complexity here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677970/hide-textoutput-when-un-click-row-of-a-dtdatatable-in-shiny-app